# Building work space, errors occurred during the build

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using eclipse `adt`, it was running fine. Now from two days it is showing **Building workspace has encountered a problem, errors occurred during the build**. For the first time, I closed the eclipse and reopened it everything went fine, but today this trick is not working. I googled this, but in their questions this error is because of updating the `sdk`, but I did not updated anything still I am getting this error.. and in some site I found the solution as `go to project properties->builders->uncheck the javascript validators`, but there was no `javascrript validator` in the `builders`. So how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the project properties -> android, 
 here change the target API and restart the eclipse. 
It worked for me.